# Difference between control flow and data flow in ssis

Tags: ssis, difference, dataflow

What is the difference between control flow and data flow in a SSIS package along with some examples please.

Thanks.

Comment: Search in search engine. u get lots of results. [How to ask Question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Discussion questions do not help. Please refer to this [meta solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/why-must-we-avoid-discussions-in-comments) on discussion in the stack exchanges

Answer (score 0):

In data flow task, it is mandatory that data needs to be made flown/transferred from a source to destination. Whereas in control flow task it is not.

Answer (score -1):

**Control Flow:**

Control Flow is part of SQL Server Integration Services Package where you handle the flow of operations or Tasks.
Let's say you are reading a text file by using Data Flow task from a folder. If Data Flow Task completes successfully then you want to Run File System Task to move the file from Source Folder to Archive Folder. If Data Flow Task failed then you want to send email to your users by using Send Mail Task. The Precedence Constraints are used to control the execution flow.

**Data Flow:**

Data Flow is the part of SQL Server Integration Services Package, where data is extracted by using Data Flow Sources ( OLE DB Source, Raw File Source, Flat File Source , Excel Source etc.). After extacting data Data Flow Transformations such as Data Conversion, Derived Column, Lookup, Multicast,Merge etc are used to implement different business logics and finally written to Data Flow Destinations (OLE DB Destination, Flat File Destination,Excel Destination,DataReader Destination ADO NET Destination etc.)

Take a look at [This post](http://sqlage.blogspot.in/2014/03/ssis-what-is-difference-between-control.html) for more details.

Answer (score -3):

Click on the Control Flow Tab and observe what items are available in Tool Box
Similarly Click on the Data Flow Tab observe what items are available

Comment: It is not an explanation at all

Comment: You might as well have posted "let me google that for you."